# Parsing JSON error

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to use a syntax I learned from here on a new application. I am getting an error when I try to parse the results. I believe I am misunderstanding something about this JSON response, as the same syntax works fine on other applications

Typical response is as follows -

```
outputs =   

[[{u'results': [{u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'Arumeru',
                                          u'short_name': u'Arumeru',
                                          u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2',
                                                     u'political']},
                                         {u'long_name': u'Arusha',
                                          u'short_name': u'Arusha',
                                          u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1',
                                                     u'political']},
                                         {u'long_name': u'Tanzania',
                                          u'short_name': u'TZ',
                                          u'types': [u'country',
                                                     u'political']}],
                 u'formatted_address': u'Arumeru, Tanzania',
                 u'geometry': {u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': -2.9567556,
                                                          u'lng': 37.0479585},
                                           u'southwest': {u'lat': -3.7703911,
                                                          u'lng': 36.541356}},
                               u'location': {u'lat': -3.2923144,
                                             u'lng': 36.8250274},
                               u'location_type': u'APPROXIMATE',
                               u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': -2.9567556,
                                                            u'lng': 37.0479585},
                                             u'southwest': {u'lat': -3.7703911,
                                                            u'lng': 36.541356}}},
                 u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political']}],
   u'status': u'OK'}]]   


output = open('geocoding_results_Tanzania.csv', 'w+')
writer = csv.DictWriter(output, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['location_lat', 'location_lng'])
writer.writeheader()

pprint([results])

for results in outputs[0]["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]:
params = {
'location_lat': results['lat'],
'location_lng': results['lng'],
}
writer.writerow(params)
```

Error -

```
    location_lat': results['lat'],
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However, when I do as advised by @Padraic

```
lat = outputs[0]["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]['lat']
lng = outputs[0]["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]['lng']
print(lat,lng)
```

I get, the correct values.

```
(-3.2923144, 36.8250274)
```

What am I doing wrong when iterating over the results?

Comment: Please show the code where the error actually happens.

Comment: Show exactly how you're getting the response. Seems like you haven't decoded the JSON string to Python objects.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Ah, so I should use json.dumps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `results[0][0]["results"]`, you have a list inside a list.

So:

```
print(results[0][0]["results"][0]["geometry"])
```

gest:

```
{'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE', 'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': -2.9567556, 'lng': 37.0479585}, 'southwest': {'lat': -3.7703911, 'lng': 36.541356}}, 'location': {'lat': -3.2923144, 'lng': 36.8250274}, 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': -2.9567556, 'lng': 37.0479585}, 'southwest': {'lat': -3.7703911, 'lng': 36.541356}}}
```

You  are accessing the wrong way, you can simply:

```
loc = results[0][0]["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]

lat, long = loc["lat"], loc["lng"]

print(lat,long)
-3.2923144 36.8250274
```

The output of `results[0][0]["results"][0]["geometry"]` is a dict:

```
{'viewport': {'northeast': {'lng': 37.0479585, 'lat': -2.9567556}, 'southwest': {'lng': 36.541356, 'lat': -3.7703911}}, 'location': {'lng': 36.8250274, 'lat': -3.2923144}, 'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE', 'bounds': {'northeast': {'lng': 37.0479585, 'lat': -2.9567556}, 'southwest': {'lng': 36.541356, 'lat': -3.7703911}}}
```

When you iterate over `results[0][0]["results"][0]["geometry"]` you are actually iterating over the keys in the dict so you are then trying to index a string using a string hence the error.

Comment: Thanks Padraic. I tried - for geometry in results[0][0]["results"][0]['geometry']:
    params = {
    "location_lat": geometry['location']['lat'],
    "location_lng": geometry['location']['lng'],
    }
But I am getting keyError: 0

Comment: @LearningSlowly. I posted what I get using the structure provided using `results[0][0]["results"][0]["geometry"]`, can you double check that you have provided the correct input format

Comment: Apologies, I did miss a line. Please see edits above. Does this clarify?

Comment: @LearningSlowly. I still get correct output using `results[0][0]["results"][0]["geometry"]`, I can also mirror your error using `results[0]["results"][0]["geometry"]`

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I think Im doing something silly. Ive updated my code to reflect where Ive used 'code' results[0][0]["results"][0]["geometry"] 'code'

Comment: a ok I see what you are doing, which lat/long do you want?

Comment: Many thanks @Padraic. Ive got a step closer. Still having issues with iterating over all the results

Answer (score 0):

So - on the line pasted on the session "Error" above you have a literal Python expresssion - `['results']` on that line is a hard-coded string inside a hardocded list, not a reference to the previous data you have decoded.  Your expression takes the `[0]`'th element from  `['results']`, which is the string `'results'`, and tries topick the `['geometry']` element from that.

Try:

```
location_lat = results[0][0][u'results'][0][u'geometry']
```

instead

Answer (score -1):

here is the pprint.pprint(result) output:

```
[[{u'results': [{u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'Arumeru',
                                          u'short_name': u'Arumeru',
                                          u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2',
                                                     u'political']},
                                         {u'long_name': u'Arusha',
                                          u'short_name': u'Arusha',
                                          u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1',
                                                     u'political']},
                                         {u'long_name': u'Tanzania',
                                          u'short_name': u'TZ',
                                          u'types': [u'country',
                                                     u'political']}],
                 u'formatted_address': u'Arumeru, Tanzania',
                 u'geometry': {u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': -2.9567556,
                                                          u'lng': 37.0479585},
                                           u'southwest': {u'lat': -3.7703911,
                                                          u'lng': 36.541356}},
                               u'location': {u'lat': -3.2923144,
                                             u'lng': 36.8250274},
                               u'location_type': u'APPROXIMATE',
                               u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': -2.9567556,
                                                            u'lng': 37.0479585},
                                             u'southwest': {u'lat': -3.7703911,
                                                            u'lng': 36.541356}}},
                 u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political']}]}]]
```

the for loop statament 'for geometry in results['results'][0]['geometry']'  just gets the below dict's key value

```
{u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': -2.9567556, u'lng': 37.0479585},
             u'southwest': {u'lat': -3.7703911, u'lng': 36.541356}
            },
 u'location': {u'lat': -3.2923144, u'lng': 36.8250274},
 u'location_type': u'APPROXIMATE',
 u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': -2.9567556, u'lng': 37.0479585},
               u'southwest': {u'lat': -3.7703911, u'lng': 36.541356}
              }
}
```

so the location info should be got as following

```
geometry = results[0][0]['results'][0]['geometry']
params = {
"location_lat": geometry['location']['lat'],
"location_lng": geometry['location']['lng'],
}

pprint.pprint(params)
```